# Creating a calculated property with data from prior calculated property in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Apologies if this is a "Well, duh!" moment but I'm trying to figure out how to reference a prior calculated property in a script and I'm at a loss after searching various forums.  The following script runs perfectly in my environment until the last line.  The $theusers system array is pulled from a .csv

```
Get-MsolDevice -All -ReturnRegisteredOwners |
Where-Object {($_.DeviceOSType -eq 'iPhone' -or $_.DeviceOSType -eq 'iPad') -and $_.RegisteredOwners.Count -gt 0 -and $_.DeviceTrustLevel -eq 'compliant'} |
Select @{L='User';E={Get-ADUser -filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$($_.RegisteredOwners -join(';'))'" -server "server.com" | Select -expandproperty name}},
@{L='EmailAddress';E={$_.RegisteredOwners -join(';')}},
@{L='Position';E={Get-ADUser -properties description -filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$($_.RegisteredOwners -join(';'))'" -server "server.com" | Select -expandproperty description}},
@{L='Office';E={Get-ADUser -properties l -filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$($_.RegisteredOwners -join(';'))'" -server "server.com" | Select -expandproperty l}},
@{L='DeviceName';E={$_.DisplayName}}, 
@{L='DeviceType';E={$_.DeviceOSType}}, 
@{L='DeviceOS';E={$_.DeviceOSVersion}},
@{L='LoginName';E={Get-ADUser -properties description -filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$($_.RegisteredOwners -join(';'))'" -server "server.com" | Select -expandproperty samaccountname}},
@{L='TrueOffice';E={$theusers | where-object {$_.SamName -like $_.LoginName } | Select -expandproperty office }}
```

Everything works except the last line.

```
User         : Doe, John Q.
EmailAddress : JDoe@server.com
Position     : DAL.Court Jester
Office       : Dallas
DeviceName   : John’s iPad
DeviceType   : IPad
DeviceOS     : 13.3.1
LoginName    : JDoe
TrueOffice   :
```

I'm trying to use the "LoginName" created from the line above but it does not seem to be passed on as a variable.

I tried replacing $_.LoginName with the actual expression . . .

```
Get-ADUser -properties description -filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$($_.RegisteredOwners -join(';'))'" -server "server.com" | Select -expandproperty samaccountname
```

. . . which created LoginName but still got blanks for TrueOffice.

On the last line, if I replace $_.LoginName with an actual login name, such as "JDoe", the "TrueOffice" information for "JDoe" is provided from $theusers, so I know the language is correct but I just can't figure out out to get LoginName to be recognized as a variable.

When $_.LoginName is changed to "JDoe"

```
User         : Doe, John Q.
EmailAddress : JDoe@server.com
Position     : DAL.Court Jester
Office       : Dallas
DeviceName   : John’s iPad
DeviceType   : IPad
DeviceOS     : 13.3.1
LoginName    : JDoe
TrueOffice   : North Texas
```

Thanks in advance for any insight into this.

Comment: What is the result of just `$theusers | where-object {$_.SamName -like $_.LoginName }`?

Comment: You can't access one property from a sibling property like that because the property (and its parent object) doesn't exist until _after_ `Select` in the pipeline.  Further, `$_` is the _input_ object — not the output object — of `Select`.  A workaround would be to wrap your `Select` in a `ForEach-Object`, inside of which you calculate and store in a variable the value on which both properties are based.  That would also allow you to invoke `Get-ADUser -filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$($_.RegisteredOwners -join(';'))'" -server "server.com"` one time instead of four.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid using `Select-Object` in this case and just use a `foreach-object` from which you cal `Get-ADUser` *once* and then return a custom PS object manually. I think the result is more flexible, readable and efficient:

```
Get-MsolDevice -All -ReturnRegisteredOwners |
Where-Object {($_.DeviceOSType -eq 'iPhone' -or $_.DeviceOSType -eq 'iPad') -and $_.RegisteredOwners.Count -gt 0 -and $_.DeviceTrustLevel -eq 'compliant'} | foreach {
    $adUser = Get-ADUser -filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$($_.RegisteredOwners -join(';'))'" -server "server.com"
    [PSCustomObject] @{
        'User"'= $adUser.name;
        'EmailAddress' = $_.RegisteredOwners -join ';';
        'Position' = $adUser.description;
        # other properties omitted . . .
        'LoginName' = $adUser.samaccountname
        'TrueOffice' = $theusers | where-object {$_.SamName -like $adUser.samaccountname } | Select -expandproperty office 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you SO much for this.  I used your example and it worked.  I just needed to add a -properties * to the Get-ADUser so it would return everything I needed.  This has helped me understand better, as well.  I really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `$_.LoginName` you are trying to access an *output* property which doesn't exist on the *input* object, `$_`.  A workaround would be to wrap your `Select` in a `ForEach-Object`, inside of which you calculate and store in a variable the value on which both properties are based...

```bsh
Get-MsolDevice -All -ReturnRegisteredOwners |
    Where-Object {($_.DeviceOSType -eq 'iPhone' -or $_.DeviceOSType -eq 'iPad') -and $_.RegisteredOwners.Count -gt 0 -and $_.DeviceTrustLevel -eq 'compliant'} |
    ForEach-Object -Process {
        $emailAddress = $_.RegisteredOwners -join(';')
        $user = Get-ADUser -filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$emailAddress'" `
            -server "server.com" -Properties 'Name', 'Description', 'l', 'SamAccountName'
        $loginName = $user | Select -expandproperty samaccountname
            
        $_ | Select @{L='User';E={$user.Name}},
            @{L='EmailAddress';E={$emailAddress}},
            @{L='Position';E={$user.Description}},
            @{L='Office';E={$user.l}},
            @{L='DeviceName';E={$_.DisplayName}}, 
            @{L='DeviceType';E={$_.DeviceOSType}}, 
            @{L='DeviceOS';E={$_.DeviceOSVersion}},
            @{L='LoginName';E={$loginName}},
            @{L='TrueOffice';E={$theusers | where-object {$_.SamName -like $loginName } | Select -expandproperty office }}
    }
```

A few notes about the above code:

- Instead of calling `Get-ADUser` once for each output property based on a user attribute, I retrieve the user object once with the exact properties that are needed.
- The email address and login name are calculated once and stored in local variables for reuse.
- There's not really any downside other than an imperceptible performance hit, but if you pass a pattern that doesn't contain any wildcard characters to `-like` (as in `$_.SamName -like $loginName`) you might as well use `-eq`.

  - If you really wanted to filter on partial string matches you could use `$_.SamName -like "*$loginName*"` or the case-sensitive `$_.SamName.Contains($loginName)` (but not `-contains`!).
- I simplified usages like `$user | Select -expandproperty name` to `$user.Name`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick schooling in what I needed to do.  It's been very helpful in understanding where I went wrong and what I need to do going forward.  Thanks for taking the time to explain, esp. the siblings objects and input objects.